# accessing a selectlist item in razor (cshtml)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, selectlistitem

I have a lookup table where i keep track of possible project status values:

LOOKUPID    FIELDTYPE        DESCRIPTION

61          PROJECTSTATUS    ACTIVE

62          PROJECTSTATUS    HOLD

63          PROJECTSTATUS    NOT ACTIVE

This is my "Index" method to grab all the projects in system:

```
// GET: PROJECTS
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.PROJECTSTATUSID = new SelectList(db.LOOKUP.Where(l => l.FIELDTYPE == "PROJECTSTATUS"), "LOOKUPID", "DESCRIPTION");
    return View(db.PROJECTS.ToList());
}
```

in the .cshtml file i have this:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PROJECTSTATUSID)
```

which displays NUMERIC values (i.e. 61/62/63)

in the Project "Index" view i want to be able to display the "DESCRIPTION" associated with those NUMERIC values instead. i.e. the "ACTIVE", "HOLD", etc.

in the "Index" method i grab those "DESCRIPTION"s in the ViewBag. so how do i access them in the razor code?

Comment: aren't you using wrong Helper. Try @Html.DropDownList

Comment: no because this is for the Project "Details" view. i use the DropDownList for the "Edit" view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This it's what you looking for:

```
  <ul>
     @foreach (var item in ViewBag.PROJECTSTATUSID as SelectList)
     {
        <li>
           Id: @item.Value <br />
           Desc: @item.Text
        </li>
     }
  </ul>
```

Comment: -Thanks for the suggestion.  I created a razor function to implement your idea.  Took me a while to mark your answer as accepted.